# Can't run included js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am running a project and need to allow the users change their own passwords. But I include the popup for my change password form at the very beginning of my php file. And include the other (.js) files at the bottom of my PHP file.

So, when i insert the js code for my change password AJAX just after the FORM i get "undefined $" error (which means i didnt include jquery). I include my .js file at the bottom but it doesnt detect my "click" on the specified button. What did i do wrong?

change_password.js file:

```
$('#change_password_submit').on('click',function() {

    alert('OK!');

    $('#change_password_form').removeClass("has-error");
    $('#change_password_confirm_form').removeClass("has-error");

    if($("#change_password").val()=="" || $("#change_password").val()==" ")
    {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Failed",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Define a password.</i>",
            color : "#C46A69",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $('#change_password_form').addClass("has-error");
        return false;
    }
    if($("#change_password_confirm").val()=="" || $("#change_password_confirm").val()==" ")
    {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Failed",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Confirm your password.</i>",
            color : "#C46A69",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $('#change_password_confirm_form').addClass("has-error");
        return false;
    }
    if($("#change_password_confirm").val() != $("#change_password").val())
    {
        $.smallBox({
            title : "Failed",
            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Passwords does not match.</i>",
            color : "#C46A69",
            iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
            timeout : 4000
        });
        $('#change_password_confirm_form').addClass("has-error");
        return false;
    }

    $.SmartMessageBox({
        title   : "<i class='fa fa fa-spinner fa-spin txt-color-green'></i> Confirmation!",
        content : "Do you want to edit the user?",
        buttons : '[No][Yes]'
    }, 
    function(ButtonPressed) 
    {
        if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") 
        {
            $.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'user_func.php',
                data : 
                {
                    'password'                  : $('#change_password').val(),
                    'password_confirm'          : $('#change_password_confirm').val(),
                    'ajax_action'               : 'change_password'
                },
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    if (msg == "no_match") {
                        $.smallBox({
                            title : "Failed",
                            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Passwords does not match.</i>",
                            color : "#C46A69",
                            iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout : 4000
                        });
                    } else {
                        $.smallBox({
                            title : "Success",
                            content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Password changed successfully.</i>",
                            color : "#659265",
                            iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout : 4000
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (ButtonPressed === "No") 
        {
            $.smallBox({
                title : "Cancelled",
                content : "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Change cancelled.</i>",
                color : "#C46A69",
                iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                timeout : 4000
            });
        }
    });
});
```

my change password for at the top:

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'>
    <form action='noaction();' class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class='form-group' id='change_password_form'>
            <div>
                <div class='icon-addon addon-md'>
                    <input type='password' id='change_password' name='change_password' placeholder='New Password' class='form-control'>
                    <label class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock' title='Password'></label>
                </div>                                          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group' id='change_password_confirm_form'>
            <div>
                <div class='icon-addon addon-md'>
                    <input type='password' id='change_password_confirm' name='change_password_confirm' placeholder='Confirm Password' class='form-control'>
                    <label class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock' title='Confirm Password'></label>
                </div>                                          
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <button id='change_password_submit' class='btn btn-block btn-primary change_password_submit'>Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

and this is how i include my js file at the very bottom of the page:

```
<!--================================================== -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
        if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
            document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>
<!-- JS TOUCH : include this plugin for mobile drag / drop touch events
    <script src="js/plugin/jquery-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM NOTIFICATION -->
<script src="js/notification/SmartNotification.min.js"></script>
<!-- JARVIS WIDGETS -->
<script src="js/smartwidgets/jarvis.widget.min.js"></script>
<!-- SPARKLINES -->
<script src="js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQUERY SELECT2 INPUT -->
<script src="js/plugin/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQUERY UI + Bootstrap Slider -->
<script src="js/plugin/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<!-- browser msie issue fix -->
<script src="js/plugin/msie-fix/jquery.mb.browser.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick: For mobile devices -->
<script src="js/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- MAIN APP JS FILE -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S) -->
<!-- <script src="js/plugin/datatables/jquery.dataTables-cust.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin/datatables/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin/datatables/media/js/TableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugin/datatables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/plugin/bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/change_password.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you do not get the alert('OK'); ?

Comment: Are you sure you've included jQuery?

Comment: Yes and yes i did...

Comment: And you included jQuery Before change_password.js?

Comment: just give me a second editing the question... Yes.

Comment: Open browser console.

Comment: what to do after that?

Comment: i just saw document.write and felt a little dizzy

Comment: maybe one of the scripts you included invoked `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: @andrew How can i prevent it, its possible...

Comment: @EceKuru not easily if it was invoked somewhere. in your code try replacing the troublesome `$` with `jQuery` if it starts working its prob due to no conflict eg `jQuery('#change_password_submit').on...`

Comment: @andrew Didn't work too... :'( I am going to cry now...

Comment: @andrew Can you please bounty this question?

Comment: @EceKuru the problem is its not easy for a dev to solve without having access to the site to debug, is this on a live server?

Comment: @EceKuru did you try as I mentioned wrapping your script in a document ready?? you said yes but you also said you were including jQuery before the script. I am 100000000% sure the alert will tell you 'OK' if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your script in a `$(document).ready(function () {});`?

Comment: @EceKuru are you sure you tried this? im pretty sure this will solve your problem

Comment: Yes. I did before you told that and i tried now again. It just doesnt work. :(

Comment: It comes when i include JS file before jQuery... So dont mind it. I solved it. Now the only issue is that if loads my .js file but does not get the "click"

Comment: @EceKuru as I am telling you, document ready will wait till all dom elemnts are in the DOM tree before trying to attach a handler (in this case a click handler). right now is attaching your handler to an unexistant element.